# AJAX Tab Panel and Binding DataTable

Tags: ajax, datatable

I am trying to find a way to bind a data table to a tab panel (within a tabcontainer and template) without doing it on page_init or page_load. OR Binding a data table to a gridview then binding that gridview to the tab panel. I know how to bind a data table to a gridview so that's the easy part. I have to be able to - on click of a button - add or create multiple tabs in that tab container.

I want the user to be able to click a button, run some queries and then make the tab container visible and bind the data from a data table to a panel at that time (then the panel to the tab container). Do this multiple times.

Can someone provide an example or explain how I can accomplsih this? Is Update Panel my answer and where can I find some good examples?

UPDATE

I found that it was very easy to bind data to a gridview within Ajax tabs. Of course you needed you script manager ajax reference declared in the asp page and web.config file. You also need to add the ajax css style to an existing style sheet. i tried using a seperate one and it didn't work.

ASP HTML

```
<AjaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" 
                            Visible="false" ScrollBars="Both"
                            CssClass="Tab2" Width="1326px" Height="464px" >

<AjaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="Empty" Enabled="true"    ScrollBars="Both" CssClass="Tab2">

<ContentTemplate>
<div style="overflow:auto;width:1287px; height: 418px;">
 <font color="white" size="1" face="Verdana">

 <asp:GridView ID="SalesOrderView1"     runat="server" BackColor="White"   BorderColor="#DEDFDE"visible="False"BorderStyle="None"      BorderWidth="1px" 
 CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" 
 GridLines="Vertical"     HorizontalAlign="Center">
 <AlternatingRowStyle      BackColor="White" />
 <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
 <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE"    ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
 <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
 <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
 <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
 <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
 <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
  <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
 </asp:GridView>
  </div>
  </font>
 </ContentTemplate>
   </AjaxToolkit:TabPanel>
      <AjaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="Empty" ScrollBars="Both" CssClass="Tab2">
 <ContentTemplate >
 </AjaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

C# Code to bind data to the gridview on click button event.

```
                        SalesOrderView1.Visible = true;
                        TabPanel1.Visible = true;
                        TabPanel1.HeaderText = Order_List[multi_order_count];
```